# perl script error: Can't exec "module": No such file or directory at ./prog line 2

Tags: perl

I need to add a openssl to Environment. This in command line is done by command 
 " module add openssl" . But this command gives an error in perl

My program:

```
#!perl -w

system ('module add openssl');
```

Answer (score -4, accepted):

From [the Perl documentation for system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html):

> If there are no shell metacharacters in the argument, it is split into
>   words and passed directly to execvp.

So, your command is being passed in as three separate commands.  Try putting quotes around it for a start. i.e.

`system ('"module add openssl"');`

If that does not fix it, it still could be related to the differences between running something in the shell and running something directly with `exec`.

In the future, it would be good practice to share information on the exact error you are getting.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. That's the whole program error is the question title i.e., perl script error: Can't exec “module”: No such file or directory at ./prog line 2"

Comment: Sorry about that; my mistake, I didn't notice that the error was in the title when I wrote that.

Comment: I tried your solution but now I get a new error                 "sh: module add openssl: not found"

Comment: anybody? I am still waiting for answer...

Comment: Oops, that does not work, because this gets passed to the shell as one long program name.  The list format of system() should work instead: `system ('module','add','openssl');`

Comment: Thanks, but now I get the old error : Can't exec “module”: No such file or directory at ./prog line 2"

Comment: Try putting the full path with module?

Comment: where is the `module` program located on your system? Try including the full directory path to the `module` executable in the call.  Such as `system ('/usr/bin/module','add','openssl');`