# Can't exec "history": No such file or directory at gatherinformation.pl line 7

Tags: perl, shell

I'm trying to call "history" from a perl script but it keeps saying "Can't exec "history": No such file or directory at gatherinformation.pl line 7." Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $fich ,">>/home/osboxes/Desktop/ConteudosServer/Plano de contingencia/history_report.txt");
`history`;
```

I have tried only using `history` in the script but it keeps giving me the same error.

I'm have been messing around with the HISTFILESIZE and HISTFILE variables to output "%h/%d -- %H:%M:%S ". 
Heres is the line in the bashrc file:

```
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%h/%d -- %H:%M:%S "
```

I have tried both of these answers:
[Can't exec No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14032741/cant-exec-no-such-file-or-directory)

[perl script error: Can't exec "module": No such file or directory at ./prog line 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11984725/perl-script-error-cant-exec-module-no-such-file-or-directory-at-prog-line)

I don't think it's usefull to start another question just to ask this: is there a way to get the `history` directly from the file `./bash_history` with date and time? I don't think it's usefull having to call shell commands to such a simple task.

Comment: can you open a shell and write `history`?

Comment: Yes, i can open the shell and write `history` and it will give me the output that i specified in `bashrc`

Comment: What is the output from `perl -MConfig -E'say $Config{sh}'`?

Comment: The backticks start a brand new shell process, so even if it worked there would be no history to show. What is it that you're trying to do?

Comment: But the `history` command won't get the history from the `bash_history` file, wich contains 300 command history (default HITSIZEFILE i guess)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `history` is a *bash* shell command, not a program in its own right

Even so, I am surprised you're getting that particular error message, as the backticks operator starts a new shell process and passes the string to it as a command, so it should work whether it's a shell process or not. I'm guessing that the default shell that Perl is using isn't bash. You can check for sure by running

```
perl -MConfig -E'say $Config{sh}'
```

But I wouldn't expect you to see any output anyway, as the new shell process will have no history, and so there should be no output from the command

Comment: Like system and exec, if the command contains no shell meta characters except spaces and tabs (and maybe other whitespace), it executes the program directly rather than invoking a shell.

Comment: I have tried the `perl -MConfig -E'say $Config{sh}'` but i don't get any output. Just a blank line.

Comment: I have tried using the same script in another machine (ubuntu server) but it gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's likely that perl is treating "history" as a stand-alone binary; the same reason why `which history` wouldn't produce anything - it's part of the shell built-in.