# How can I save the /.bash_history with this format day:month hour:minute:seconds - command

Tags: linux, bash

I had this little script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @a = `history`;
print @a;
```

here is the question I asked about the error in this script: [Can't exec "history": No such file or directory at gatherinformation.pl line 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34242066/cant-exec-history-no-such-file-or-directory-at-gatherinformation-pl-line-7)

As I mentioned in the question: I was messing around with the `HISTFILESIZE` and `HISTFILE` variable to get the output as I desired.

Since I can't perform that script, is there anyway I can get the same result directly from the `/.bash_history` file with the desired format?

Comment: You probably cannot do this. The history file is supposed to be replayable

Comment: You are using `HISTTIMEFORMAT` in your other question, which is used to control how the timestamp is displayed by the `history` command. The file itself is not configurable; it always uses a UNIX timestamp. The `.bash_history` file should not be considered human readable or usable; it is essentially a private database for the shell itself.

Comment: Is there anyway I can achieve the final goal without `history` in a perl script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a way to get the `history` directly from the file
>   `./bash_history` with date and time?

Sure, we can read the file and convert the timestamps:

```
use POSIX qw(strftime);
my $histfile = "$ENV{'HOME'}/.bash_history";
open HIST, "<$histfile" or die "$histfile: $!";
while (<HIST>)
{
    if (/^#(\d+)$/) { print strftime("%h/%d -- %H:%M:%S ", localtime $1); next }
    print $_
}
```